# Running Balance/Total on 2 columns

Tags: sum, cumulative-sum

I have the following Table in Azure MSSQL:

ID,
Charge,
Payment

ID is the Primary Key and unique, Charge and Payment are Numeric.

ID  charge  payment
1 10 null
2 null 10
3 40 null
4 null 30

I want to do the following query:

```
select *, 
SUM(charge)-sum(payment) OVER (order by id) AS Balance
from Table T
order by id asc
```

Which in the above data sample would look like this:

ID  charge  payment balance
1 10 null 10
2 null 10 0
3 40 null 40
4 null 30 10

However that query fails, complaining I need to do add a Group by clause, however if I run the following

```
select *, 
SUM(charged) OVER (order by id) AS totalCharged
from table
order by id
```

That works fine - I feel like I've missed something obvious.

I should also note there are other columns that are in the final query but are omitted from here since they aren't relevant to the logic.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was missing something obvious.
I changed the source query to use 0 instead of Null and then did the following:

```
select *, 
SUM(charged - payment) OVER (order by id) AS balance
from table
order by id
```

So figured it out myself whilst thinking upon the porcelein throne.